# Considerations for changing your power bi license provider

Tags: powerbi

Good evening,

Currently I have purchased power bi licenses with a provider "X", if I decide to change to provider "Y" and buy the licenses from him, is there any migration that has to be done?

I mean if I have to go from vendor 1 tenant to vendor 2 tenant or similar? or what would the procedure be?

Thank you so much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tenant is yours, licenses is just a number. You can combine licenses from different resellers with licenses bought directly from Microsoft. If you want to stop working with the current reseller, buy enough Power BI Pro licenses from another source and cancel the existing subscription.